# Не работает toggler меню в Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

Не работает toggler меню в Bootstrap 4. В чем причина?

```css
#mainmenu {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: #e3f2fd;
  border-bottom: 15px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px white;
}

.dropdown.has-megamenu {
  position: static;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.submenu2 {
  height: 291px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
  white-space: normal;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav id="mainmenu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light ">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="mainNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">

        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" d="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link2</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu1 multi-column columns-3 ">

          <div class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-header" href="#">
                      <h5>Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-header" href="#">
                      <h5>Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">

                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-header" href="#">
                      <h5>
                        Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>

                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>

                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>


      <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" d="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link4</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu2 multi-column columns-3 ">

          <div class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-5">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-header" href="#">
                      <h5>Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-header" href="#">Submenu</a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-5">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                      <h5>Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас был указан неверный `data-target`. Укажите `data-target="#mainNavbar"`.

```css
#mainmenu {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: #e3f2fd;
  border-bottom: 15px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px white;
}

.dropdown.has-megamenu {
  position: static;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.submenu2 {
  height: 291px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
  white-space: normal;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav id="mainmenu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light ">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="mainNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">

        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" d="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link2</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu1 multi-column columns-3 ">

          <div class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-header" href="#">
                      <h5>Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-header" href="#">
                      <h5>Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">

                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-header" href="#">
                      <h5>
                        Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>

                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>

                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>


      <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" d="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link4</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu2 multi-column columns-3 ">

          <div class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-5">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-header" href="#">
                      <h5>Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-header" href="#">Submenu</a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-5">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                      <h5>Submenu</h5>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```